# PowerShell: concatenate strings with variables after cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I often find myself in the situation where I have to concatenate a string with a variable after a cmdlet. For example,

```
New-Item $archive_path + "logfile.txt" -type file
```

If I try to run this, PowerShell throws the following error:

> New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+'.

Am I not concatenating the string correctly? I'd like to not have to declare another variable before each cmdlet that I do this in (e.g., `$logfile = $archive_path + "logfile.txt"`, and then do `New-Item $logfile -type file`). Also, I won't always be concatenating a file path.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You get that error because the PowerShell parser sees `$archive_path`, `+`, and `"logfile.txt"` as three separate parameter arguments, instead of as one string.

Enclose the string concatenation in parentheses, `()`, to change the order of evaluation:

```
New-Item ($archive_path + "logfile.txt") -Type file
```

Or enclose the variable in a subexpression:

```
New-Item "$($archive_path)logfile.txt" -Type file
```

You can read about argument mode parsing with [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-5.1).