# Concatenate Cmdlet output with string

Tags: powershell, concatenation

How do I output to the host the combination of the output of a command and a literal string **on a single line**?

I'm trying to combine: `(Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint X:).EncryptionPercentage` (which returns `12`) with the literal `'% complete'` as follows:

```
(Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint X:).EncryptionPercentage + '% complete'
```

In return I expect to get:

> 12% complete

Instead I get the error *Cannot convert value "% complete" to type "System.Single". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."*

How can I do this on a single line?  I've searched for a solution but apparently don't know how to phrase this question because I keep getting information on how to concatenate strings or variables, but not command output. Examples: [PowerShell: concatenate strings with variables after cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446831/powershell-concatenate-strings-with-variables-after-cmdlet)

Comment: `(Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint X:).EncryptionPercentage.ToString() + '% complete'` or `'{0} % Complete' -f (Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint X:).EncryptionPercentage`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With PowerShell when you use `+` it will try to cast the second argument to the type of the first. `EncryptionPercentage` is a `Single` so it will try to cast `'% complete'` to an `Single` which throws an error.

To get around this, you can either cast `EncryptionPercentage` to string preemptively.

```
 [string](Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint X:).EncryptionPercentage + '% complete'
```

Or you can do string interpolation inside double quotes, using a subexpression `$()`

```
"$((Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint X:).EncryptionPercentage)% complete"
```

As TessellatingHeckler points out, the `.ToString()` method will also convert to a String

```
(Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint X:).EncryptionPercentage.ToString() + '% complete'
```

And you can use the format operator `-f` to insert values into a string. Where `{}` is the index of the comma separated arguments after `-f`

```
'{0} % Complete' -f (Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint X:).EncryptionPercentage
```

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in the error message, PowerShell is trying to convert (cast) `'% complete'` to the type System.Single.  That's because the output of your command is a number.

To get the output you're asking for, use `[string]` before the command to cast the number output into a string.  Then both elements of the command will be treated as a string:

```
[string](Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint X:).EncryptionPercentage + '% complete'
```